# $lookup not working in my node js as it was working in my compass test

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have an aggregate on my nodejs app, that is not looking up the referenced document, but when I tested it manually on compass it shows the results. So maybe I am doing something wrong with mongoose.
This is my code inside my app

```
 const notifications = await Notification.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                destinationUserId: userId
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "rides",
                localField: "ride",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "rideInfo"
            }
        }
    ]).skip(offset).limit(limit).sort(`${order}${fieldForOrder}`);
    console.log({notifications});
```

When I do this i get this result on that console.log

```
{
  notifications: [
    {
      _id: 5e9ca58c486ac8a1e0bc80e5,
      authorUserId: 'abfb258d-3ce8-40a4-a214-45afe7c71687',
      destinationUserId: '1ef488c7-9078-4378-9ac9-1e9f650048e5',
      title: 'Your ride is due',
      message: 'You should be on way to your destination.  You have 1 passengers. ',
      state: 'read',
      rideId: 5e9ca4d4486ac8a1e0bc80e4,
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2020-04-19T19:25:00.014Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-04-19T21:26:09.079Z,
      rideInfo: []
    }
  ]
}
```

So I am getting an empty array in rideInfo.

When I do the same query on compass I do get information on ride Info
[image]

Comment: it seems that your `localField` in the `$lookup` isn't the same as the one used on compass, Mongoose has `populate` function btw to fulfils the same thing as `$lookup`

Comment: Yes you are right sorry I dont know how that happened